# C - if/else statement

Tags: c

I'm fairly competent with if/else statements, and this is a really old assignment that I ended up turning in partially complete. But I still wanted to know exactly why my code wouldn't work.

I want my user to input name, height, and sex. My code will then display an entire sentence that says "Name is X cm tall and is a male" or "Name is X cm tall and is a female."

When I input name and enter, it immediately then skips displays both the height AND the sex. Regardless of what I input after that, it then ends the program.

Input name: Jack
Input height in cm: 180
sex(M/F): 
Computer $

I've been playing around with this code for a while now, but I have been stuck for a while now. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  char name[30];
  char sex;
  float height; 

  printf("Input name: ");
  scanf("%s", name);
  fflush(stdin);
  printf("Input height in cm: ");
  scanf("%f", &height);
  fflush(stdin);

  printf("sex(M/F): ");
  scanf("%c", &sex);
  if (sex == 'M') 
  {
    printf("%s is %f cm tall and male", name, height);
  }
  else if (sex == 'F')
  {
    printf("%s is %f cm tall and female", name, height);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Worked when I compiled under c++ express.. (although I stupidly put "f" not "F" .. so didnt print the first time.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can see it only skips the sex part - which is very sad to be honest :-)).

> it immediately then skips displays both the height AND the sex
>
> Input name: Jack Input height in cm: 180 sex(M/F): Computer $

You can try this:

```
scanf(" %c", &sex);
       ^
```

The space causes `scanf` to eat blanks before reading a character.

Comment: Wouldn't the value still be the same? Sorry if I'm wrong, I would have though the compiler would fill in the blanks.

Comment: @TheBlueCat `scanf` is very particular about its input. Some specifiers consume the space, some don't.

Comment: To elaborate on the reason, it's because when trying to read the sex as a single character, there is already the newline in the buffer and the `scanf` sets the sex to the newline. Adding a space in front of the format code tells `scanf` to skip whitespace (i.e. space, tabs and newlines).

Comment: Okay, I just tried your solution and it worked on GCC/Linux 3.4. Why does this happen, I don't understand why there needs to be a space?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I intentionally used fflush(stdin); to renew the input buffer. Shouldn't that have sufficed for this issue?

Comment: Also @cnicutar thank you very much! And yes the sex was definitely the most important part.

Answer (score 0):

`fflush(stdin)` is a very bad idea (undefined behavior). You should replace this call with an other function call, for example this one :

```
static void
clean_stdin(void)
{
    int c;
    do {
        c = getchar();
    } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

With it, it seems working.

Comment: Yeah, I've been told multiple times from compilers and friends to avoid using scanf and gets, but I fear I've gotten accustomed to it after being taught to use these functions.

Comment: @Danny, why not just use fgets?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an ampersand on line 9:

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

shoul be:

```
scanf("%s", &name);
```

maybe this helps

Comment: scanf("%s", name); is enough. No need for &

Comment: @TheBlueCat I am told that because the string in C is already a character array, which is a pointer value, adding & on top of that would be repetitive.

Comment: @TheBlueCat It's not technically wrong, since taking the address of an array is the same as using the array itself. I.e. `name == &name`. However, it only works for arrays, not for pointer, so if you have e.g. `char *nameptr = name;`, then using `&nameptr` will actually return the address of the pointer, not what it points to.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
printf("sex(M/F): ");
scanf("%s", &sex);
```

Answer (score 0):

To read a single character from stdin you have to use getchar() instead of scanf("%c", &c)
Or change the variable type of sex to char[2] and use scanf("%s", sex)